# vim: create new file similar to edit with gf (goto file)

Tags: vim

In vim, with `gf` you can "Edit the file whose name is under or after the cursor".

Exist some similar map to create a edit a new file like `gf`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `<c-r><c-f>` (or `<cfile>`) to get the filename over the cursor.

```
nnoremap cgf :e <c-w><c-f><cr>
```

For more help see:

```
:h c_CTRL-R_CTRL-F
:h <cfile>
```